# Avoid max char limit c#

Tags: c#, file-io

To exceed the max path limit in c# you apparently need to concatenate your drive path with `@"\\?\"` at the beginning of it. If I do this then I get a drive path with the following at the front

`\\\\?\\\\\\server\\share\\...`

Now if I look for the file/folder it will fail because of illegal charachters in the path (I assume the `?`) so how can I adopt the approach outlined on Microsoft's website ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx)) correctly?

```
foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
{
    String s = @"\\?\" + filePath;

    if (filePath.Length > 255)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(filePath);
    }

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(s);
        folderSize += finfo.Length;
    }
}

foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
    folderSize += GetDirectorySize(dir);
```

Comment: can you show some code on where you try to use a long path? are you creating a file or folder or reading an existing file nested in a very long path? Read my answer below.

Comment: I am trying to calculate tghe size of a set of share drives, they are really big in some cases and as such the paths often exceed 255 chars

Answer (score 2):

Standard System.IO doesn't support path longer than 260 characters.

But it seems there's a library with extended-length path support:
http://alphafs.codeplex.com/

I personally haven't tried it so far.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should add all those slashes before the path, I think you did not understand everything what was written in MSDN here:

> **Maximum Path Length Limitation**
>
> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following
>   paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is
>   defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following
>   order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by
>   backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the
>   maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string"
>   where "" represents the invisible terminating null character for
>   the current system codepage. (The characters < > are used here for
>   visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.)
>
> **Note:** File I/O functions in the Windows API convert "/" to "\" as part
>   of converting the name to an NT-style name, except when using the
>   "\?\" prefix as detailed in the following sections.
>
> The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to
>   permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of
>   32,767 characters. This type of path is composed of components
>   separated by backslashes, each up to the value returned in the
>   lpMaximumComponentLength parameter of the GetVolumeInformation
>   function (this value is commonly 255 characters). To specify an
>   extended-length path, use the "\?\" prefix. For example, "\?\D:\very
>   long path".
>
> **Note:** The maximum path of 32,767 characters is approximate, because
>   the "\?\" prefix may be expanded to a longer string by the system at
>   run time, and this expansion applies to the total length.

as you can read there,:

> The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to
>   permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of
>   32,767 characters.

this is the key for your issue, if you need to create or access to a path longer than ~260 chars you should use specific Windows APIs.

Comment: And you need to directly (ie. P/Invoke) the APIs: the .NET classes do not support extended length paths (like they don't support alternate data streams).

Comment: Any idea which specific one please :)

Comment: show your code editing your question above. we must see what you are doing to be able to suggest a replacement. No crystal balls here...

Comment: WOW. .NET can't handle paths longer than 256 chars?  That makes it about useless to write any kind of file explorer.